# cannot update the property of vue object inside axios success callback

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have axios callback and I want to update the property of vue object and I have 2 way binding between the `input` tag and the `edited` property so that text box is hidden or displayed depending the `edited` property. when I update `edited` property to false inside callback, the textbox won't be hidden. but textbox is hidden or displayed when I updated outside axios callback.

```js
editBtnClicked: function (index) {
    var promise = null;

    axios.put('/rest/project', this.projects[this.currentIndex]).then(response => {
        // textbox won't be hidden or displayed even if this statement is executed.
        this.projects[this.currentIndex].edited = !(this.projects[this.currentIndex].edited);
    });

    // textbox is hidden or displayed when this statement is excuted.
    // this.projects[this.currentIndex].edited = !(this.projects[this.currentIndex].edited);
}
```

Could anyone tell me why? and you can check the full code: https://gist.github.com/inherithandle/e61a5ab2809581a5d36de08b4e4349f1

Comment: Code looks correct to me, we're going to need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help you further. Can you confirm that the `then` success callback function is actually being called?

Comment: I put `console.log` statement inside the callback and saw the message on the screen. It's hard to create an MCVE example because I can't upload my backend stuff. But I can upload my full html code. could you check this out? sorry for the dirty code : https://gist.github.com/inherithandle/e61a5ab2809581a5d36de08b4e4349f1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is that is caused by the property `edited` of `project` item in `projects` array is added to the `project` dynamically.
[Adding property to Ojbect](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

When adding the property to Object, you have to use `$set`.

> Due to the limitations of modern JavaScript (and the abandonment of Object.observe), Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion.
> However, it’s possible to add reactive properties to a nested object using the Vue.set(object, key, value) method:

Please try the below code in `line 181` and other lines that changes `edited` of `project` item in your source code of github.

```
this.$set(this.projects[this.currentIndex], 'edited', false);
```

Comment: I thought `$set` was not required because two-way biding is working outside callback.

Comment: @inherithandle, you have to use $set for Vue to be sure that detects the changes of Object value.

Answer (score 0):

Your `currentIndex` always be 0, and your two if statements will always return false.

Comment: The attached code missed some part of the original source code.